# keep excel not visible when other excel documents are opened

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with UserForm1. I have the following codes (see below) as soon as I open the file only UserForm1 is displayed and the file is not. So far everything fits but when I open another excel file, the invisible excel file (where UserForm1 is) becomes visible again. But I want it to remain invisible and only UserForm1 is visible, even if I open and close other excel files.

Code in my module:

```
Sub showLoginForm()
    If isSheetVisible Then
        ' Only Hide this workbook and keep the other workbooks visible
        ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
    Else
        ' There is no other workbook visible, hide Excel
        Application.Visible = False
    End If
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub

Function isSheetVisible() As Boolean
    ' Checks if any workbook except the current one is visible
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If Not wb Is ThisWorkbook Then
            Dim win As Window
            For Each win In wb.Windows
                If win.Visible Then isSheetVisible = True
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Code in my workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    UserForm1_Initialize 'ignore it not relevant for the question
    showLoginForm
    
End Sub
```

Showing the problem visul (sorry cant get video)

Opening my test vba:
[image: test vba]

all good sofar now opening another excel file and my text excel will open as well, what i dont want:

[image: problem]

I might need a code where when another file is opened after UserForm1 opened, UserForm1 is automatically asked if another file has been opened, if yes then ThisWorkBook.visible = False is used again. If so, how do I write such a code so that it will automatically be execute without doing anything?

Comment: `when I open another excel file` is it opened by users or VBA code?

Comment: @taller by me so user.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue on M365.

Comment: So, I am opening the excel with vba than my UserForm1 opens and the excel workbook not sofar so good. But if i open now anothwr excel file. The hidden workbook (from userform1) opens which was hided. So thats my problem annd habe m365 as well :(

Comment: @taller I edited my question with pictures. I tried with new blank excel file and paste my codes but getting same issue.

Answer (score 0):

- In VBE, right click on `ThisWorkbook` > View Code > paste the code in Code windows
- The code hide the host workbook (which has UserForm) when users open a new workbook.

***Note:*** The code is not guaranteed to resolve the OP's issue because I am unable to reproduce the problem.

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim WithEvents xlApp As Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set xlApp = Application
End Sub

Private Sub xlApp_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Me.Windows(1).Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I just added a code:
ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False

to my showloginform on else and solve it.
But, now i have second problem. If I close another excel doc. the UserForm1 also closes... do you know why?